# How to run coverlet on .NET projects not using the Sdk style projects?

Tags: .net, code-coverage, coverlet

I would like to try [coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet), but the only examples I could find talk about running it through `dotnet.exe`. My problem is that our projects do not use the Sdk style, they are old .NET projects targeting .NET 4.7.2

How can I run coverlet with them?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on VS2017 building against .NET Framework 4.6.1 and have .NET Core SDK v2.1.511 installed. I haven't figured out a way to run coverlet without using `dotnet`, but this works for me:

Run `Install-Package coverlet.msbuild` in the package manager console for all your test projects (**only**).

Then add something like the following task to your build script:

```
Task("Coverage")
    .IsDependentOn("Build")
    .Does(() =>
{
    StartProcess("dotnet" , new ProcessSettings {
        Arguments = new ProcessArgumentBuilder()
            .Append("test")
            .Append("/p:CollectCoverage=true")
            .Append("/p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover")
    });
});
```

By adding `OpenCoverReportsPath = "**/*.opencover.xml"` to my `SonarBeginSettings` I now get coverage reports in SonarQube.